# How to open Mono GUI applications on OS X?

Tags: macos, sound-volume

I tried [Fiddler](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono) and [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) on [Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) and both these applications start, their icons jump on the Dock, but no window is displayed.

Comment: For now this is not a good question. You need to give some more information. What is Mono, what version did you use? And except for OS X we need to know what version as well. Do you have checked the Console.app for some more information? Have you tried the stable Mono version 2.x as well?

Comment: Mono is an open source cross platform implementation of the .NET Framework. It's used to run some Windows applications on OS X for example.

Comment: I informed it was OS X Mavericks on the tags

Comment: I tried the stable version of mono.

Comment: Are there error messages appearing in **/Applications/Utilities/Console.app**?

Comment: Just a suggestion: have you tried launching the applications from X11/XQuartz? Try launching X11.app, opening xterm, and then launching the applications with `mono <prog.exe>`

Comment: I still think this question is of low quality.

Answer (score 3):

This might seem like a silly suggestion but are you giving the applications enough time to launch?

I tried installing and launching both applications. The first launch took a surprising amount of time; as you describe the icon appears in the Dock almost immediately but then no UI seems to appear. However if you leave it long enough the UI then does appear (about 4-5 minutes on a 2011 Macbook Pro).

Subsequent launches are a lot faster.

If you are curious to see what it is doing you can run this `sudo opensnoop -v | grep mono-sgen` in a Terminal when you launch the applications. On my system the delay on initial launch just seems to be Mono reading all the fonts on my system and caching them in `~/.cache/fontconfig`. Luckily it just seems wants to do that once.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a UI Toolkit to interface with the Mono framework.

[FAQ: Basics](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_General#Basics)

> **What is Mono™ exactly?**
>
> The Mono Project is an open development initiative sponsored by Novell to develop an open source, UNIX version of the Microsoft .NET development platform. Its objective is to enable UNIX developers to build and deploy cross-platform .NET Applications. The project implements various technologies developed by Microsoft that have now been submitted to the ECMA for standardization.

[FAQ: GUI applications](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_General#GUI_applications)

> **Will Mono enable GUI applications to be authored?**
>
> Yes, you will be able to build GUI applications.
>
> Indeed, that was the main driver for the creation of Mono. Today you can use Gtk# to develop GUI applications on Windows, Linux and MacOS X.
>
> We are also developing a complete Windows.Forms implementation.
>
> A list of pros and cons on the various APIs is available in our [Gui Toolkits](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) page.

You can check [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/download/) (audio player) as a working example. If you mount the disk image and inspect the package contents (`Banshe.app/Contents/Resources`) you can see that it uses Gtk 2.0 for the UI.